# Conditional ESC, ideas?

Tags: vim

I often need to enter insert mode just to make changes on a specific line, and would like know if there is a way to enter insert mode in a way that when I am done editing on that line, hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> gets me back to normal mode.

I am aware of the `r` command for replacing a single character, I guess what I want is something like that but for a line.

Comment: Note that `R` works for any number of characters in the same way as `r`, but that behavior is different than you describe in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following mapping makes the key combination `gi` enter insert mode just like `i`, but hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> in this insert mode will return you to normal mode. Just add the following lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd! InsertLeave * silent! iunmap <CR>
nnoremap gi :inoremap <C-V><CR> <C-V><ESC><CR>i
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?

```
:imap <Enter>   <Esc><Enter>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it sounds like you want ***R*** but the rest of the question makes it seem like you're also wanting to have an easier time replacing characters under the cursor, avoid Esc or maybe insert mode in general. So here are some random suggestions that may help:

Delete the word under the cursor and say in command mode: ***diw***

Delete the whole line and stay in command mode: ***dd***

If you hate having to reach up to the Esc key, you can make it so something else - like hitting ***j*** twice in a row from insert mode - does an Esc: ***imap jj <esc>***

Or you can have vim automatically switch back to normal mode after a few seconds of inactivity: ***au CursorHoldI * stopinsert***

Answer (score 0):

If like me you find reaching the ESC key a bit of a stretch, then use Ctrl-[ - Vim has that defined as an alias to it by default.

Comment: Actually it's not vim doing that, it's ASCII :) `[` is 0x5b, escape is 0x1b, and "control" works by clever bitmasking. (To see the pattern, note that `A` is 0x41, and control-A is 0x01). For bonus points, figure out `^@` and `^?`. :)